# Calling JavaScript function within a JSP page

Tags: javascript, function, jsp

I am trying to call a in-page JavaScript function from inside a JSP page. Here is the code snippet, but the JavaScript functions are not being called when the JSP page is rendered on the client. Anything wrong following this method of calling?

```
<%     //more jsp code
  if(count>0) { response.sendRedirect("main.jsp"); %>
<script type="text/javascript"> setCookie('user','<%=user1%>',1); </script>
<% } else { response.sendRedirect("index.jsp"); %>
<script type="text/javascript"> alert("please enter proper credentials and log in again");  </script>
<%    }  // more jsp code %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to send an HTTP redirect and output some HTML at the same time.

The HTML will appear on the page that will be displayed to browsers configured to **not** automatically follow redirects (which is practically none of them) so nobody is going to see the page which includes that HTML.

You need to put the HTML on the page you are redirecting to (or, in the case of the cookie setting code, set the cookie with JSP/HTTP instead of client side JavaScript).

Comment: Finally, this worked:

`Cookie cookie = new Cookie ("emp",empid1); 
cookie.setMaxAge(24 * 60 * 60); 
response.addCookie(cookie);`

Looks like I forgot the addCookie method last time I tried this. Thanks!